# Dummit and Foote Abstract Algebra Proposition 4.1.1

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism

I'm struggling to understand the following proposition from Dummit and Foote:

> **Proposition 1.** For any group $G$ and any nonempty set $A$ there is a bijection between the actions of $G$ on $A$ and the homomorphisms of G into $S_A$

Here is how my understanding of the proposition:

1. "The actions of $G$ on $A$" means $L = \{g \cdot A \mid g \in G\}$ where $g \cdot A = \{g \cdot a \mid a \in A\}$
2. "The homomorphisms of G into $S_A$" means $M = \{h : G \to S_A \,|\, h(g_1g_2) = h(g_1)h(g_2)\}$

To show that there exists a bijection, I would have to show $|M| = |L|$. How do I show this (in the case that my understanding is correct)? I know I'm missing something obvious; Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have also a look at Theorem $1.6$ in Conrad's [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf). For showing a bijection one can also show the existence of maps $\phi$ and $\psi$ with $\phi\circ \psi=\psi\circ \phi=id$. You don't need cardinalities (and $|L|$ is missing).

Comment: So the idea is to identify actions of $G$ on $A$ with homomorphisms of $G$ to $S_A$, and not to compare cardinalities.

Comment: @DietrichBurde -- I defined $L = \{g \cdot A \mid g \in G\}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde - Oh, yes! Fixed.

Comment: An action is (in this context) a certain kind of map $\phi:G\times A\to A$. Usually $\phi(g,a)$ (for $g\in G,a\in A$) is abbreviated $ga$ when $\phi$ is understood. But if we're talking about the set of all $\phi$s, then $ga$ becomes ambiguous! In any case, for any single choice of action $\phi$, we have $gA=\{ga\mid a\in A\}=A$ so $L=\{gA\mid g\in G\}=\{A\}$ is a singleton set (and its one element $A$ is not an action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can identify the set of the action of $G$ on $A$ with:
$$\mathcal A=\{\phi:G\times A\rightarrow A| \;\phi(1,\cdot)=\text{Id},\;\;
\phi(g_1g_2,a)=\phi(g_1,\phi(g_2,a))\}$$
and the other set with $M$.

Now the map $M \stackrel{F}{\rightarrow} \mathcal A$ defined by:
$F(h)=\phi $ such that: $$\phi(g,a):=h(g)(a)\;\; \text{where}\;\; h(g)\in H$$

$\phi$ is an action because $h$  is a homomorphism.
$F$ is obviusly injective.

For surjective: give an action $\phi$ we define a homomorphism  $f\in H$ such that:

$$f(g)(a):=\phi(g,a)$$
Using the property of the element of $\mathcal A$ it's easy view that $f$ is a homomorphism and by construction $F(f)=\phi$.